# How do I create another link to view the images in a lightbox - Galleria plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, galleria

I am using the Galleria plugin on my site and all works fine. When the main image is clicked it opens a lightbox so the user can view the images.[example](http://islandthrills.com/index.php?option=com_jomres&Itemid=40&lang=en&task=viewproperty&Itemid=40&property_uid=14)

I am trying to create an another link ( apart from the image itself ) lower down the page to achieve the same thing.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance. Most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After you've called your `Galleria.run('#selector')` method, you can write your link html, adding a data-imgIndex data-attribute. Give your clickable links a class, like 'show-lightbox.'

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' class='show-lightbox' data-imgIndex='1'>Link text here</a> 
<!-- link to first image in galleria set -->
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-lightbox', function() {
    var gallery = Galleria.get(0),
        index = $(this).data('imgIndex');
    index = +index //convert string to int with preceding plus-sign
    gallery.openLightbox(index); // open lightbox to img at specified index
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yo, @jonathan-gillmor did this help, or no?